Showpare 6 Plugin:String configuration value not updating in Twig template
I'm working on a Shopware 6 plugin and facing an issue where a string configuration value from the config.xml file is not being updated in the Twig template, although boolean values are updating correctly.
config.xml
<input-field type="text">
    <name>nameDomain</name>
    <label>CNAME Domain</label>
    <label lang="de-DE">CNAME Domain</label>
</input-field>


Config.php
public function __construct(SystemConfigService $systemConfigService, ?string $salesChannelId = null) {
    // ...
    $this->cname = !is_null($systemConfigService->get($this->path . 'nameDomain', $salesChannelId)) ?
        (string) $systemConfigService->get($this->path . 'nameDomain', $salesChannelId) : '';
    // ...
}


BaseSubscriber.php
private function initializeSwagData(): SwagData {
    $swagData = new SwagData();
    if ($this->getConfig() && is_object($this->getConfig())) {
        $SwagData->assign([
            'active' => $this->getConfig()->isActive(),
            'cname' => $this->getConfig()->getCname()
        ]);
    }
    return $SwagData;
}

When I dump() the SwagData object in the Twig template, the boolean fields like active are updated correctly based on the configuration values, but the string field cname remains an empty string, even after changing the value in the configuration. Any help would be appreciated.

Share more of Config.php please - what's the difference in loading cname versus active?
